# Web cam streaming with Flash?

Tags: php, flash, webcam

I am looking to build an application that has a couple different modes. The first involves a client creating video (in the browser) from their webcam which will in turn be saved on the server. The second involves two clients chatting real-time with their web cams.

My background is in PHP,MySQL,CSS, and Jquery so when it comes to all these proprietary technologies created by Adobe I start getting lost in the mix.

I see that they have "Adobe Flash Builder 4.5 for PHP" for a hefty price tag. What does that offer me? Is it necessary? What is the cheapest (while still effective) method to go about using flash for this type of application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flash Builder is a development tool, but you don't have to buy that to develop for the Flash platform (although it helps), you can use any code editor and the compiler that comes with the free open source Flex SDK:

http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Flex+SDK

There is a 45 day trial period for Flash Builder, so one way to get started could be to download that and use it to get acquainted with ActionScript/Flex development, and after the trial period you can use the free compiler.

For streaming video, you also need a streaming media server, and if you don't want to buy Adobe's Flash Media Server, there is the open source alternative Red5 - http://www.red5.org

I guess you could also investigate hosted streaming services, as an alternative to hosting your own media server (and possibly won't even need to develop your own Flash client), from payed services to free services like http://bambuser.com but I don't know that much of what is offered and possible that way and if it can meet your needs.